# How to export Selenium IDE test suite

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I have saved 10 test cases in my Selenium IDE test suite.
I need to send the test suite to my friend. For that, I have to mail the test suite as well as test cases since the test suite refers to individual test cases.

Can I export the test suite and just mail the test suite alone separately without mailing the test cases along with it?

Answer (score 1):

No there isn't such possibility. The test suite is only an html file that keeps the names of the test cases their position and their order.